# Json not able to access via dot operator

Tags: javascript, json, ajax4jsf

I am using a4j jsFunction to send data to server and receive Json from server

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="submitData"
action="#{imageRetriveBean.saveData}" data="#{responseNodesPathsBean}"
oncomplete="processData(event.data)">
    <a4j:param name="param1" noEscape="true" value="myFunction()"
    assignTo="#{imageRetriveBean.requestJsonMsg}" />
    <a4j:param name="param2" noEscape="true" value="getFloorNo()"
    assignTo="#{imageRetriveBean.floorNo}" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

In the processData function below

```
function processData(data)
{
    console.log(data);
    var dataObj = data.responseJsonMsg;
}
```

The console.log prints the data correctly. Following is the output.

```
({responseJsonMsg:"{//my data}"})
```

but I am not able to access the data using the data.responseJsonMsg

The console gives the error

```
TypeError: data is undefined
```

Images of code where error occurs and the error output on Chrome

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2LrAStQ7RleOUtHMTRfT2sxams/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2LrAStQ7RleU09Vdll1VURaT2c/edit?usp=sharing

Please help me know where I could be wrong.
Thanks

Comment: please create a fiddle for it. as it will be easy to debug

Comment: A sample fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/ajayfame/eGvK7/16/
I have added links to images also
It works on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

if that is the output of console.log, then it is not a javascript object, you need to parse it `JSON.parse(data)`, though from what you are showing that is not a valid json string anyway so it would still error out. It would need the parenthesis removed, responseJsonMsg would need quoted etc. You need to have your server side code output a valid json string

it should look like, if `//my data` is supposed to be actual data

`{"responseJsonMsg":{
     "name":"patrick",
     "where":"here"
  }}`